# setTimeout with async/await not running as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout, auth0

I am trying to automatically refresh a token using setTimeout.
Due to some reasons I am not using setInterval . Here's the code snippet:

```
let token = '';
let expire = '';
const getToken = async () => {

    const options = { /* some valid options that gets token */}

    try {
        expire = jwtDecode(token).exp * 1000 - Math.floor(new Date().getTime()) - HOUR
        if (expire > HOUR) return expire
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Err, proceeding to next.")
    }


    try {
        const response = await rp(options) //using request-promise
        token = JSON.parse(response).access_token
    } catch (err) {
        //retry logic in N minutes
    }

    setTimeout(async () => {
        await getToken();
    }, expire)

    return expire;
}
```

The idea is to let the code fail on first run, which should then automatically make a request for a token. It then sets the expiry time for the next refresh round.

I tested it with smaller `expire` like 1000, 5000..etc, and they seemed to work fine.
However our server was down today, and we found out the token was not refreshed. Any hints would be appreciated.

Edit: typo in code

Comment: The `setTimeout()` mechanism doesn't understand `async/await` as far as it's callback functions go.

Comment: A function that is named `getToken` which returns an expiry... but as a side-effect modifies a global variable `token`... hmmm, that's dirty.

Comment: @Pointy I can't yet understand the connection between async/await and the function progressing fine with smaller numbers but fails with bigger expire values. Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thank you!

Comment: You should consider running in strict mode, because `expire` is only defined in the `try` block scope, and so, the last `return expire` is going to return `undefined`.

Comment: @trincot in the actual source code we have a better name, right now it's modified to keep the name short. Sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: Yes, but side-effects are not so "best practice".

Comment: Well it's been the case forever that `setTimeout()` ignores any return value from the callback function. That's going to include the implicit Promise returned from your `async` callback function; that promise will therefore vanish into thin air and the underlying generator function for the callback will never be invoked.

Comment: I'm still very new to javascript and I'm trying to understand what you mean @Pointy, do you mean getToken does not get invoke the third time because of how setTimeout tosses out the initial returned promise?

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout`. Just await recursively. `getToken = async = () => { await getToken(); };`. simplified of course

Comment: I'm trying to understand what problem you're trying to solve?  When you say you have a problem "when our server is down", which server is it.  Is it the server that you're trying to get the token from?  Or the server that runs this code?  Also, the "let it fail the first time" logic just seems like poor design to me.  You can use an `if` to provide a default value for `expire` rather than trying to run something you know will fail.

Comment: I don't mean to discourage you but if you're still "very new" to JavaScript the `async/await` mechanism is certainly one of the most complicated parts of the language to understand.